# Does java.io.File.listFiles(FilenameFilter filter) already sort the file object?

Tags: java, list, filter, filenames

Good day.

I was wondering if `java.io.File.listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)` returns an already sorted object.

Here is my code:

```
String[] files = FIUtil.getFilesList(FIConstants.getIFDirectory(filePrefix), 
FIConstants.VALID_INPUT_FILE_SUFFIX,filePrefix);

   log.debug("=== LOOKING FOR FILES IN ===" + FIConstants.getIFDirectory(filePrefix));
   log.debug("=== Inside directory ===");
   for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++){
       log.debug("=== "+files[i]); }
```

---

```
 public static String[] getFilesList(String directory, final String suffix,String prefix)
   {
      try {
         File fileObject = new File(directory);
         return fileObject.list((new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.startsWith(prefix) && name.endsWith(suffix);        
        }
    }));
  }
  catch (SecurityException se) {
  }
  return null;
}
```

My files in the directory are **not sorted**.
But when I check the listing of files in my logs, they **are already sorted**.

Comment: you got very lucky if you see some sorted output... there are no guarantees what-so-ever about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not sort by name, date or anything.

Comment: Correct, according to the API docs: There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [`File.listFiles()` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) there is no order guranteed

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

Comment: I sometimes think that SO would have only 10% of the questions, if people would only read the docs... still +1 for quoting it